# Area under navbar in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I keep failing to make proper use of a navbar.
In my base.html I have this code fragment in the body section.
(or should the navbar be in the head?!)

```
  <body>

          <div class="row">
              <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

                      <div class="navbar-header">
                          <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://...">Company</a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                              <li><a href={{ url_for("strategy_index") }}>Strategies</a></li>
                              <li><a href={{ url_for("data_index") }}>Data</a></li>
                              <li><a href={{ url_for("view_index") }}>Views</a></li>
                          </ul>
                      </div>
              </div>
          </div>



            {% block content %}

            {% endblock %}

  </body>
```

I then use

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
        <div class="row">

         HELLO WORLD

        </div>

{% endblock %}
```

However, the HELLO WORLD is hidden below the navbar. How can I block the area occupied by the navbar?

Many thanks
Thomas

Comment: Is it possible to post some CSS?

Comment: I use the standard bootstrap.css file without any modifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
padding-top: 70px;
```

to your `body`. It's right there in the [documents](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top):

> The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the top of the body. Try out your own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.

Comment: Ok, this is almost what I want. I am adding a large and lengthy vertical list below this. The scroller bar extends over the navbar. Is there a way to make this bar only covers the space below the navbar?

Comment: No, you can't. The navbar is fixed to the top, so you can't move the scrollbars down and they'll go over it - just like their demo: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/